# Can we select first row of data from column in sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with multiple data for same ID. I want to get the first row data for the ID.

I have added the below SQL that I have tried.

```
SELECT
"client"."id",
"client"."company_name",
"client_details"."address"
from Client
LEFT OUTER JOIN "client_details" ON ("client"."id" = "client_details"."client_id")
```

Since I have multiple address for the same ID, can we get only the first id?

Currently the output I get is 2 rows with different addresses.

Comment: How are you defining "first id"?  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets; there is no "first" row.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5f5524/12 check this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

You can add to your SQL `LIMIT 1` and in case you want to be sure the order you can also add to your SQL `ORDER BY...`

Comment: You can add a LIMIT in a subquery inside the LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 1):

You can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (c.id) c.id, c.company_name, cd.address
from Client c left join
     client_details cd
     on c.id = cd.client_id
order by c.id, ?;
```

The `?` is for the column that specifies the ordering (the definition of "first").  I am guessing that `cd.id` is what you want.

Note that this query removes the double quotes and introduces table aliases.  This is easier on both the eyes (to read) and the fingers (to type).

Answer (score 0):

use `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
SELECT
"client"."id",
"client"."company_name",
"client_details"."address",row_number() over(partition by "client"."id" order by "client_details"."address") as rn
from Client
LEFT OUTER JOIN "client_details" ON "client"."id" = "client_details"."client_id"
)A where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is a field you can order the results by you could use a lateral join e.g.

```
SELECT
"client"."id",
"client"."company_name",
"client_details"."address"
from Client
left join lateral (
    select *
    from client_details cd
    where cd.client_id = client.id
    order by [some_ordering_field]
    limit 1
) "client_details" on true
```